# ¿Cómo implementar funciones asíncronas en arduino (C++)?

Tags: c++, arduino, asincronismo

Estoy creando un programa que correrá en arduino que involucra que mueva un motor y que prenda varios leds. Para hacer que el arduino espere un tiempo se usa la función **delay();** a la que se le pasa una cantidad de milisegundos. Sin embargo, mientras se está en el delay **no se puede hacer nada mas** hasta que el tiempo termine, prácticamente pone al arduino a dormir.

Necesito algo similar a lo que en javascript es un **setTimeout()**, donde paso un callback y la cantidad de milisegundos, pero para implementarlo en mi arduino con C++.

He buscado en internet y encontrado una solución que usa la función **millis()**:

```
unsigned long lastMillis;

void setup() {
  lastMillis = millis();
}

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - lastMillis) >= 1000) {
    doSomething();
    lastMillis = millis();
  }
}
```

> Este código lo saqué de https://youtu.be/YP9xQWqFOKg

Es una buena opción, sin embargo, como tengo que controlar una cantidad considerable de salidas, el void loop quedaría lleno de condicionales, me gustaría mas una función a la que le paso otra función (callback) y la cantidad de milisegundos que quiero que espere (Ya lo dije, como JavaScript).

Había pensado en yo mismo crear una función así:

void setTimeout(**???** callback, int milliseconds) {}, y que esta función agrege a un array un objeto que tiene el callback y la cantidad de milisegundos, pero **¿Qué tipo de variable sería el callback?**

Además de otra función que luego se encargaría de revisar si el tiempo necesario que declaramos con **setTimeout** ya pasó, y si es así, ejecutar el callback. Esta función que llamaría executeAsync() la pondría dentro del loop(), y así simpre estará revisando de forma asíncrona. Además por dentro tendría el condicional que menciono mas arriba.

La cuestión es, qué tipo de variable es el callback y qué tipo de variable es el **array lleno de objetos** que a la vez está lleno de **callbacks** y **int** con milisegundos.

¿O que otras soluciones se les ocurren para manejar la asincronía?

Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Lo que usted necesita es una [interrupción](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/).

Answer (score 1):

La manera estándar de programar intervalos en Arduino, por ejemplo, ejecutar una función cada cierto tiempo, es la siguiente:

```
void loop() {
  static unsigned long prev = 0;
  unsigned long now = millis();
  
  if (now - prev >= 1000) {
    prev = now;
    funcion_periodica();
  }  
}
```

La función `millis()` cuenta milisegundos de ejecución desde el booteo. La variable `now` tiene el tiempo actual en milisegundos y `prev` tiene el último tiempo en que se ejecutó la función.

La diferencia `now - prev` me da los milisegundos transcurridos desde la última ejecución de `funcion_periodica`. Si ya se ha cumplido el intervalo requerido, se ejecuta la función y se actualiza acordemente el valor de `prev`.

Es importante notar que `prev` es una variable `static`, es decir, conserva su valor a través de sucesivas ejecuciones de `loop`. Esto permite *recordar* el tiempo de última ejecución.

**Beneficios**

El código no bloquea. Si no es el momento de hacer la llamada, sigue de largo.

Los intervalos son exactos. No importa cuanto tiempo demore en ejecutar `funcion_periodica`(o el resto de `loop`), las llamadas a la función serán siempre al intervalo escogido.

### Múltiples funciones

Si tienes múltiples funciones que realizar a distintos intervalos, sólo hay que repetir el esquema.

Veamos este programa que ejecuta dos funciones a intervalos de 5 y 15 segundos respectivamente. Para simplificar, la "función" serán simplemente imprimir una línea y luego ejecutar un `delay` de largo aleatorio para simular la demora de una llamada real.

Hay que fijarse en que tenemos que recalcular `now=millis()` antes de procesar cada función.

Usamos la variable `retardo` para registrar el retardo (ms) aleatorio a aplicar a cada "llamada" a la función.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long prev1 = 0;
  static unsigned long prev2 = 0;
  unsigned long now;
  int retardo;

  now = millis();
  if (now - prev1 >= 5000 || prev1 == 0) {
    prev1 = now;
    retardo = random(10,1000);
    Serial.print(now / 1000); Serial.print(" tick. Retardo="); Serial.println(retardo);
    delay(retardo);
  }

  now = millis();
  if (now - prev2 >= 15000) {
    prev2 = now;
    retardo = random(10, 1000);
    Serial.print(now / 1000); Serial.print(" tock!!! Retardo="); Serial.println(retardo);
    delay(retardo);
  }
}
```

produce una línea con el runtime en segundos, la salida de la "función" y el retardo aleatorio impuesto, en milisegundos. Como se aprecia, cada función se ejecuta en

```
0 tick. Retardo=977
0 tick. Retardo=539
5 tick. Retardo=483
10 tick. Retardo=588
15 tock!!! Retardo=590
15 tick. Retardo=882
20 tick. Retardo=34
25 tick. Retardo=648
30 tock!!! Retardo=63
30 tick. Retardo=839
35 tick. Retardo=280
40 tick. Retardo=225
45 tock!!! Retardo=592
45 tick. Retardo=972
50 tick. Retardo=667
55 tick. Retardo=633
60 tock!!! Retardo=737
60 tick. Retardo=719
65 tick. Retardo=800
70 tick. Retardo=542
75 tock!!! Retardo=313
75 tick. Retardo=479
80 tick. Retardo=649
85 tick. Retardo=957
90 tock!!! Retardo=410
```

### Overflow/Wraparound

Al trabajar con `millis()` en Arduino hay que tener presente que el valor hace wraparound cada 49.71 días. Esto significa que `millis()` va retornando valores crecientes hasta que vuelve a empezar desde cero.

Esto se debe a que los milisegundos se manejan como `unsigned long`, que mide 4 bytes, cuyo máximo valor es 4_294_967_295 milisegundos, o ~50 días.

**No se pueden sumar millis() en Arduino**

Si tienes dos tiempos t1 y t2, t1 + t2 puede dar overflow, y terminar con un valor menor que t1 y t2.

Las operaciones con tiempos e intervalos siempre se calculan por diferencia, en base al tiempo trascurrido desde un evento inicial hasta el presente.